# Apache hanging after updating website files

Tags: apache-2.2, server-crashes

I have a Linux server running Apache and PHP.

Sometimes (about once every dozen or so), after updating the PHP files and/or static files, Apache will hang some 5 to 10 minutes afterwards (depending on how active the server is).

The processes will become unresponsive one after another until all processes are effectively "locked".

The files are deployed using a git checkout. As I understand it, git does atomic file updates and I've managed to rule out opcache by resetting it after every deployment.

Has anybody ever experienced a situation like this of have an idea on what might be the cause?

Comment: Log file entries?

Comment: @Sven: The PHP logs are clean, the Apache access and error logs just show a gap in otherwise ordinary traffic. The Apache log itself contains only a single message, which is the cause of the problem: `[Wed Mar 30 13:39:51.904068 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2641] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting`. Changing `MaxRequestWorkers` merely delays the crashing; already tried this before.